# Unable to download CSV File from javascript

Tags: visualforce, lightning, javascript, csv

I have created a custom button. When user click on that button, it will redirect to a visualforce page. There I have written some code to download CSV file.

Code:

```
       const rows = [
                        ["name1", "city1", "some other info"],
                        ["name2", "city2", "more info"]
                    ];

                    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

                    rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {
                        let row = rowArray.join(",");
                        csvContent += row + "\r\n";
                    });
                    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
                    var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
                    link.setAttribute("download", "mydata.csv");
                    link.setAttribute("target", "_self");
                    document.getElementById('success').appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
```

Above code will get invoked from a button click.
When I use this page from Classic, it is working good.
But, when I use in Lightning, a corrupted file is downloaded (Refer Attachment).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works in Lightning Experience (LEX) from VF page.
The only thing, which doesn't work - when I click on button it initiates downloading csv file named **download.csv** in Chrome or randomly generated name in Firefox (not **mydata.csv** as you specified in JS).

**Reason why it doesn't works in LEX?**
In the Salesforce app and Lightning Experience, Visualforce runs inside an iframe that’s inside the larger /lightning container. I guess because of that browsers ignore name specified in download attribute.

Also, I have tried your code directly in JS of lightning component/app. And, everything works as expected.

**As a workaround**, you can create for LEX separate button.
And here you have three options:

1. You can create lightning app with the same JS code on button click.
   User should be redirected to your lightning app /c/YourAppName.app instead of VF page.
2. You can create lightning component which implements `force:lightningQuickAction` with the same JS code on button click. No redirects is required for this solution.
3. You can create lightning component which implements `force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes` with the same JS code on button click. User should be redirected to your lightning tab /lightning/n/YourTabName instead of VF page.

Comment: It is a List Button (URL Type). Only "Solution 2" is working. For Solution 1,3 I'm getting redirection problems. It is redirecting to unknown URL. So, I created a Lightning Quick Action and placed in parent object page layout. 

Thanks for your help....

Comment: could you help me take a look at this one when you have time?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312168/lightning-container-blocks-download