# Lightning container blocks download

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This is my lightning container code, it wraps my application

```
<aura:component controller="Controller" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:container  aura:id="box" class="container" onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}" src="{!$Resource.Zip + '/index.html'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

My application has a download button, basically, when users click on it, I will generate a file and prompt the download dialog so users can save that file.

When opening the console, I see this error:

```
Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more details.
```

Then I inspect the iframe which is generated by lightning component:

```
<iframe class="container" frameborder="0" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-popups" data-aura-rendered-by="426:0"></iframe>
```

To fix the bug, I need to add `allow-downloads` to the sandbox of the iframe. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do so. However, you could send the file through a message to the component, and have it generate the download in the usual fashion:

```
handleMessage: function(component, message, helper) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = message.payload.filename;
  a.src = message.payload.contents;
  a.click();
},
```